# Is there a clean way to access properties of an object that can be undefined but is only rendered when it is defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wrote a "Loaded" component that only displays its children when the object being loaded has been loaded.

```
export const Loaded = (props: ILoadedProps): JSX.Element => {
    if (props.loadState === 'error') { return <p>Error</p>; }
    if (props.loadState === 'loading') { return <p>Loading...</p>; }
    return <>{props.children}</>;
};
```

And I use it in a component like this:

```
<Loaded loadState={loadState}>
    <h3>{server!.name}</h3>
</Loaded>
```

I can guarantee that when the loadState is 'loaded', server will be defined, but I'm still getting "cannot read property 'name' of undefined" errors at run time. I think this happens before the server object is loaded, so it's still attempting to read the name property even though it won't be rendered by the Loaded component. I can think of some ugly ways to circumvent this, like using

```
server ? server.name : ''
```

But is there a cleaner way to work around this?

Comment: According to what pattern you say this is ugly ?

Comment: The second option of the ternary operator should never be rendered, so it's giving the illusion of an option when there really is none. Also, imagine I'm displaying many more properties than just the server name, I don't want to have ternary operators everywhere.

Comment: Actually this a good practice for React. I do not see a better way, or destruct all needed attributes and conditionally render them with `&&` operator

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if `Loaded` was a function, how would you call it ?

```
Loaded(loadState, server.name)
```

Which would give you the same error you currently have.

Basicaly your are trying to resolve a property which exist based on a condition before evaluating that condition.
So one way or another `server.name` has to be inside a condition.

There is no single/magic solution but it's worth noting that the "ugly" way you are refering to is actualy a fully documented react concept:

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html